# JavaScript DOM access for returns from a web service URL

Tags: javascript, xml, web-services, cross-domain

I am working on a project where I put a web service URL (cross domain) into a script source attribute that is dynamically created and I see the return, but it also says "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed" before the response. I am told to ignore this and that the response follows that. I understand how to parse the response to get the URLs that I need from it, but I can't access the data.

Basically, I created an iframe in the head of my document, then put a script tag with the src attribute as the URL to the web service. I can see the response in Firebug, but I can't access the value. I have the following code, where "sourcetext" is the tag name in the XML that is returned:

```
testResponse = toString(document.getElementById("testIframe").getElementsByTagName("sourcetext"));

console.log("value of test response == " + testResponse);
```

The response from the console is:

> value of test response == [object Window]

I don't know how to access that and use that value as a variable so that I can parse it into the required bits and pieces.

Comment: can you put in the ***raw*** reply? try putting in the address bar the url and paste here everything that it replies.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What the heck is the iframe used for? Please show the code that creates the iframe and script tag.